# Excessive battery consumption

Tags: power-management, battery

I've tried the powertop method, but really it didn't help at all. The system power saving settings are quite plain,providing no help compared to Windows 10. I am now unfortunately forced to charge my laptop twice a day for doing really simple tasks: using the web and programming in C.

I want to find a way to save battery so that I don't have to charge my laptop two times a day not only because it is frustrating,but repeatedly charging and discharging a battery is for sure not a good thing for its health.

I have the 18.04.3 LTS release,Intel i5 8265U, 4GB of RAM,128GB SSD & 1TB HDD, Nvidia GeForce MX110 GPU. All I did is execute the `sudo powertop --auto-tune` command and all of the listed items in the tunable tab turned "Good".

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Since you didn't tells us anything about your Ubuntu release, hardware configuration, usage pattern, what you actually did, etc., there's no way we can help. You're essentially asking "Why does my car squeak?" on an internet forum.

Comment: Well i have the 18.04.3 LTS release,Intel i5 8265U,4GB of RAM,128GB SSD & 1TB HDD,nvidia geforce MX110 GPU.All i did is execute the sudo powertop --auto-tune command and all of the listed items in the tunnable tab turned "Good".That's it

Comment: Add this comment to your question

Comment: I already edited my question,i will keep my mind doing that for any future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an NVidia graphics chip and a CPU with embedded graphics: recent Nvidia drivers use a technique known as Optimus to enable the power-hungry NVidia chip only when necessary, and use the integrated Intel video otherwise (which for you would be most of the time).

Needless to say, on Windows this is set by default.

On Linux this technique is supported out of the box by the Nvidia closed-source drivers but not by the Nouveau open-source driver which is the one installed by default, so a simple solution is to switch to the Nvidia drivers (can' tell how they are named on 18.04, unfortunately). I didn't measure the battery draw but on my machine this made the average temperature go from 60°C to 30°C, so I assume there were significant energy savings.

It appears that you can do the same, keeping the Nouveau driver and using an additional software called Bumblebee, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Concept was understood but can you please elaborate/clarify on what should i do?

Comment: My solution was to install the Nvidia driver (this seems to uninstall or at least disable the Nouveau driver). It should be available in your Software Center. You can measure your power drain before/after with `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now` (the value is in µW, and you lust be on battery)(my Core I5 9400H idles around 15W). Googling for optimus/bumblebee may point to other solutions.